# Most efficient way of creating XML array of ImageView

Tags: android, arrays, xml, layout, imageview

I'm new to android programming and was wondering what the best way was to create an array of ImageViews instead of just making imageview1, imageview2, imageview3 etc. I also hope that the way you guys suggest allows the opportunity of putting them in a layout.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for a ListView or GridView?  If not, then there's nothing you can do in an XML to create an array of ImageViews.  In your code however, you can iterate over their parent view's children.

Comment: Please elaborate on the second part of your comment?

Comment: Let's say you have many ImageViews inside a LinearLayout, then in your code you can get a reference to that LinearLayout and do a for loop over `layout.getChildCount()` and then treat them like an array if you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample code assumes that you have images : image1.jpg , image2.jpg and image3.jpg
in your project drawables folder. The format of the images can be different

1. Create a array of images

   `private int[] images = {R.drawable.image1,
               R.drawable.image2,
               R.drawable.image3,
               R.drawable.image4};`
2. Set up a BaseAdapter

   ```
   class ImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
       int[] images;
   ```

   `public ProductList(int[] images) {
       this.images = images;
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return images.length();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
       return images[position];
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_layout, null);
       }

       return convertView;
   }`

   }
3. Initialize your grid view or list view

`mImagesView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView_images);

mImagesView.setAdapter(new ImagesAdapter(images));`